# MySQLi error messages encoding

Tags: php, mysqli, utf-8

I've got DB in UTF8 and everything if fine except one thing - when I write to file $mysqli->connect_error, it is written in cp1251, not utf8.

```
if ($mysqli->connect_errno)
    file_put_contents('error.log', 'Ошибка: '.$db->connect_error, FILE_APPEND);
```

In file I can see 'Ошибка: ', but then goes text in wrong encoding. How can I set utf8 for MySQLi error messages?

Comment: How exactly are you creating the `$mysqli` connection...?

Comment: @deceze
`$mysqli = @new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'xxx', 'mydb');
if (!$db->connect_errno) $mysqli->set_charset('utf8');`

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is available here http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php

OOP Approach

```
$mysqli->set_charset("cp1251");
```

Manual approuch

```
mysqli_set_charset($connection, "utf8");
```

Comment: I talk about connection errors. So I don't have connection to DB. Your code gives me `mysqli::set_charset(): Couldn't fetch mysqli`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set character encoding before connection:

```
$mysqli = mysqli_init();
$mysqli->options(MYSQLI_SET_CHARSET_NAME, "utf8");
$mysqli->connect(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
```

Or for error printing you can convert encoding:

```
echo mb_convert_encoding($mysqli->connect_error, 'utf8', 'cp1251');
```